# View sessions in Visual Studio when debugging a asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, session

Is there a way to view ongoing sessions in Visual studio while debugging a asp.net application?

And if there is, can you kill the sessions somehow?

I need this cause I need to check what, and how to fix, the problems that occurs when a session indeed has died and the user tries to do something that requires the specific session.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a way to see it, and its content.
While stepping though the code, stepping over line when the session I need to check is used, you can see it and its content in the "Autos" window. (Debug -> Windows -> Autos).

Cannot kill it though.

Answer (score 0):

Would putting Trace = "True" in your page directive solve your issue? or are you asking whether the VS has a built in tool to manage sessions? if so, as far as I know it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Ah!
In the Autos window I could edit the session value to null, and getting the result I wanted.